# Writing Arabic to a CSV file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read from an RSS feed and save in a CSV file using python 3. It's a simple task, but I am unable to save the Arabic text. It prints in Arabic in the command prompt, but will not save the Arabic text in the CSV file. It will save it like this:

```html
Ø£Ø­Ø¯Ø§Ø« Ù…ÙŠÙ†ÙŠØ§Ø¨ÙˆÙ„ÙŠØ³.. ØªÙˆØ³Ø¹ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø­ØªØ¬Ø§Ø¬Ø§Øª Ø¨ÙˆÙ„Ø§ÙŠØ§Øª Ø£Ù…ÙŠØ±ÙƒÙŠØ© ÙˆØªØ±Ø§Ù…Ø¨ ÙŠÙ„ÙˆÙ‘Ø­ Ø¨ØªØ¯Ø®Ù„
```

However the command prompt is able to print Arabic text like this:

```html
أحداث مينيابوليس.. توسع الاحتجاجات بولايات أميركية وترامب يلوّح بتدخل الجيش
وفيات البرازيل تتجاوز فرنسا.. تساع وتيرة الشفاء عالميا وترقب لقاح صيني نهاية العام
```

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import feedparser
import csv

url= "https://www.aljazeera.net/aljazeerarss/a7c186be-1baa-4bd4-9d80-a84db769f779/73d0e1b4-532f-45ef-b135-bfdff8b8cab9"
feed = feedparser.parse(url)
#print (feed.entries)
csv_file = open('AljazeeraAR.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow(["Story #", "Title", "Publish date"])

i = 0
for post in feed.entries:
    title = post.title.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    published = post.published.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    print (title)
    writer.writerow([i, title, published])
    i = i+1
```

Any help?

Comment: The code works fine for me. (I removed the encode().decode() sequences because together they do nothing: they convert a string to UTF-8 and then back again to Unicode.) How are you viewing the output file?

Comment: I am using Microsoft excel 365.

Comment: You have chosen the wrong encoding on import.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you know what should I change in the code?

Comment: Import means in Excel. You have to tell Excel that it's a UTF-8 file when you read it. There is nothing wrong with your code other than the extraneous encode().decode() calls.